# Why does LDH-1 peak later than CK-MB in acute myocardial infarction?

Tags: cardiology, biochemistry

As a marker of AMI, different enzymes are used. Creatine Kinase-MB peaks within 24 hrs and returns to normal relatively quickly. Where as LDH-1 peak appears later (~72 hrs) and stays high for a week.

What can be the biological basis of this finding?

> Reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK545216/

Comment: It's good to cite sources for information in your question; it demonstrates you've made some effort towards an answer, and prior research is required for questions on this SE site.

Comment: I have added a reference.